# Oracle 10g and Active Directory not behaving as expeted

Tags: oracle, active-directory

I'm trying to connect to our Oracle 10g 64bit database running on a Windows 2003 server authenticating with an Active Directory user.

I found this weird results on our Development environment which I cannot replicate on the testing environment (same setup, different Active Directory)

I created a user as "OPS$DOMAIN\USER" and works ok if I log-in locally from the server, for example, running SQLPLUS / would connect directly without asking for username/password.
SHOW USER would return "USER is "OPS$DOMAIN\USER"".

The weird thing happened when I tried to log-in from my computer (win 7 32bit oracle 11 client) logged as domain\user. 
SQLPLUS /@MYINSTANCE did not work... it wouldn't connect, asking me for a valid user/password.

After several attempts, a colleague suggested creating the user "OPS$USER" without indicating the domain. This does not work when I try and connect locally, but it works when I connect from my machine. 
So now, SQLPLUS /@MYINSTANCE from my computer works, and SHOW USER returns "USER is "OPS$USER"".

Makes any sense?

Finally, we tried the same on our Testing environment, where it all seems to work as expected (only works if I use "OPS$DOMAIN\USER").

Any ideas why might this be happening? My machine is part of the Development domain environment, before you ask :D

I'm starting to believe this has nothing to do with Oracle config, but maybe some weird setup on our Dev AD.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `REMOTE_OS_AUTHENT` is probably set to false. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams180.htm

Comment: it's not :( i checked that one.